# Simple DB query

Tags: sql

I have two tables, users and classes. I need to show the classes count of each user with user ID and I have to show those users as well .. with no classes. how to do it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Users.id, Users.username, COUNT(*) AS classes 
  FROM Users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Classes ON User.fk_class_id = Classes.id 
       GROUP BY Users.id, Users.username
```

Comment: grouping by class.id would return an error on most databases, because users.username wasn't in the group by & being without an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

I think a subselect is probably the easiest way to achieve this.

```
SELECT U.id, numClasses = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM classes WHERE userID = U.id)
  FROM Users U
```

Comment: It's equivalent to the LEFT JOIN in Dex's answer, though Dex's is more liable to be efficient depending on the optimizer

Comment: You're right, I didn't follow through the logic of the left outer join returning the multiple rows to count, rookie mistake on my part.  For some reason I thought it would return users per Class, which it won't.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.user_name, a.user_id, count(b.class_name)
from user as a
left join class as b
on a.class_id = b.id
```